# What does 'Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol' mean?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run a program but it won't compile, I get errors. I have changed things, but doesn't seem to work. The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "StackLS.h"
using namespace std;


 int main()
   {
int answer;
char symbol;
char n, N;
StackLS stack;
bool balenced = true;

      do {
    cout << " ********** MENU ********** " << endl;
    cout << " 1. Basic Brackets () " << endl;
    cout << " 2. Standard Brackets ()[]{} " << endl;
    cout << " 3. User-Defined brackets " << endl;
    cout << " Please enter your choice: " << endl;

switch (answer){
case 1: 
    cout << "Current Setting: () " << endl;
    cout << "Enter your expression followed by a ; : " << endl;
    cin >> symbol;

    do {    

      if (symbol = '(')
    stack.push( '(' );
      else 
      if (symbol = ')' )
      {
      if (stack.isEmpty())
        balenced = false;
            else {
              symbol = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
    }
if (balenced)
    cout << "Expression is well-formed" << endl;
else
    cout << "Expression is not well-formed" << endl;
       }
           }
    while (symbol != ';' && balenced);
    stack.pop();

        }
       }
      while (answer != 'n' || 'N');

    } // end main
```

I haven't finished the program. I wanted to make sure that what I have so far will compile before I move on to the next case. Now I will post the errors I am getting. They are:

1. 1>e:\c++ language 2\well-formed expression checker solution\well-formed expression checker project\main.cpp(11): warning C4101: 'n' : unreferenced local variable
2. 1>e:\c++ language 2\well-formed expression checker solution\well-formed expression checker project\main.cpp(11): warning C4101: 'N' : unreferenced local variable
3. 1>e:\c++ language 2\well-formed expression checker solution\well-formed expression checker project\main.cpp(22): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'answer' used

1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.

1. 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall StackLS::top(void)const " (?top@StackLS@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function _main
2. 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall StackLS::push(int const &)" (?push@StackLS@@QAEXABH@Z) referenced in function _main
3. 1>E:\C++ language 2\Well-Form ed Expression Checker Solution\Debug\Well-Formed Expression Checker Project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Thanks for the help.

Comment: From the compiler error messages, I'd guess that 1) `n` is an unreferenced (unused) local variable, 2) `N` is an unreferenced local variable, and 3) `answer` is used before it is initialized.  I'd recommend removing the unused locals and initializing `answer`, for starters.

Comment: Those are be warnings; the errors are coming from the linker.  Looks like you haven't properly linked the StackLS library.

Comment: Lea - paste your makefile here too please.

Comment: A "Makefile" is the instructions for building a program with a "real" compiler. Visual C++ doesn't use them.

Answer (score 3):

The warnings are just that -- warnings. They don't stop your program from compiling, but you should look at them and try to fix them.

Your program actually compiles OK; the errors are keeping it from *linking*. That means that after your code has been compiled into machine code, and it's being built into a `*.exe` file,it turns out that some pieces are missing. It looks as if the `StackLS.h` file comes with either a C++ source file, or a *.lib or *.dll file; whatever you have, those need to be included when the executable is built, to supply those missing pieces.

Comment: I do have the stackLS.h file included in the header of the main.cpp. I also have a stackLS.cpp.

Comment: Right. What I'm saying is that stackLS.cpp either (1) isn't included in the project, so the linker can't find it, or maybe (2) if you wrote this yourself, maybe some of the methods declared in the `*.h` file aren't implemented in the `*.cpp` file; in particular, the `top()` and `push()` functions with the signatures mentioned in the linker errors.

Comment: Ok, well I have the `stackLS.cpp` file in the folder with the other files. I'm not sure but maybe it's the second thing you said, but I'm not sure how to tell if it is and/or how to fix it.

Comment: Well, is there a definition for a method `void push(int const &)` in `StackLS.cpp` ?

Comment: yeah, it is `void StackLS::push(const elemType& item)
// precondition: this stack is not full
// adds item to this stack
{
 Node *newNode = new Node;
 newNode->data = item;
 newNode->next = topItem;
 topItem = newNode;
} // end push`

Comment: OK, there you go! We didn't know that StackLS involved templates. The simple explanation is that the template definitions need to be visible at the point of instantiation, or the code won't be generated. I can't tell exactly what you've got, but the simplest and most flexible fix would be just to move the whole definition of the template class into the header file: that's generally how template classes are done.

Answer (score 1):

It has  compiled, you got some Warning about unused Variables. 
Linking has failed and so what you are missing is the file where StackLS is implemented.

Just including the header does not makes them "implemented".

So you need  something like
  StackLS.cpp or the like

You don't  have  posted that.

Comment: I do have a `stackLS.cpp` file. I included the `stackLS.h` file in the `main.cpp`

Comment: Then you have to compile it and add it to the linker commmand line. Something along g++ Main.o StackLS.o -o my_program should do

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (probably) not with your code, but with the way in which you are invoking your compiler/linker.

You need to compile the source file where `int StackLS::top() const` and `void StackLS::push(int const &)` are defined, and give the result to your linker that when linking your executable.

Answer (score 0):

You program used a library called StackLS. This could either be precompiled library or some source code.

You add references to this library using the `#include "StackLS.h"`, to allow the compiler to compile your code. This creates a compiled version of your code.

The next stage is linking your compiled code with the compiled StackLS library.  This is the job of the Linker. These days the same program (compiler) usually makes all the calls needed to do this step too (though you can link your self), though technically it's a different step to compilation.

If StackLS is your code, then you must compile that too, or if it's a precompiled library, you need to tell the linker where to find it.

In your make file, you need to add a reference to the StackLS source code or library (it's usually a .dll or .lib type file in this case).

Answer (score -1):

Remove the lines:

char n, N;
StackLS stack;

and see how you go.